# difference between (list a) and '(a) in Clojure

Tags: clojure

For the following clojure code,

```
(def a 1)
'(a)
[a]
```

why `'(a) = (a)` and `[a] = [1]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quote applies itself to the content of the list as well.

```
'(a)
;; ~ (quote (a))
;; ~ (list 'a)
;; => (a)
```

Use `(list a)` instead.

```
(list a)
;; => (1)

;; this works too
`(~a)
;; => (1)
```

See http://clojure.org/special_forms#quote